# Jackson custom generic deserializer

Tags: json, rest, generics, serialization, jackson

I need to create custom jackson generic typed bean deserializer.
T is bean implementing IEntity.

```
public interface IEntity {
    public int getId();
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = RestLoaderRequestDeserializer.class)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class RestLoaderRequest<T extends IEntity> Serializable {
    private T entity; // entity to load field to
    private String className; // actual class of entity
    private String fieldName; // fieldName to lazy REST load

// constructors(non parameter & all parameter), getters, setters, hashCode, equals, toString
}
```

Now what I have is this:

```
public class RestLoaderRequestDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<RestLoaderRequest<IEntity>> {

    @Override
    public RestLoaderRequest<IEntity> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        try {
        ObjectCodec objectCodec = jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = objectCodec.readTree(jp);
        String className = node.get("className").textValue();
        String fieldName = node.get("fieldName").textValue();

        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);

        JsonNode rawEntityNode = node.get("entity");
                    // How to deserialize rawEntityNode to T based on className ?

        RestLoaderRequest<IEntity> request = new RestLoaderRequest<IEntity>();
        request.setClassName(className);
        request.setFieldName(fieldName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
    }

}
```

1) How to do auto-deserialization of entity based on className?

Comment: Can you also provide the JSON you're trying to deserialize?

Comment: That was good question because the "entity" field wasn't serialized at all. I ended up writing my own custom serializer and then I knew how to deserialize it. I'll post correct answer later. But thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that handling of type information and handling of payload data are separate.
So regular JSON (de)serializers are not supposed to handle types at all: rather, separate `TypeSerializer` and `TypeDeserializer` are used. This is done to prevent explosion in number of combinations; there are couple of TypeSerializer/-Deserializer implementations (for different inclusion mechanism), but hundreds of value (de)serializers.

Custom (de)serializers can obviously break this separation, when you have full control. But core Jackson has this separation, and you can see examples in standard handlers.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the info. I'll check that soon.